# Firebase FCM API with Ruby - RestClient::RequestTimeout: Request Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, rest-client

I'm using FCM to provides remote notification, an using ruby on rails as api to perform push notifications, using ResClient to do the http request (also tried HttpParty). But its getting this error:

```
 RestClient::RequestTimeout: Request Timeout
 from /Users/dowicz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:427:in `rescue in transmit'
```

And here is where I make the the post:

```
def self.send_with_notification_key(options = {})

  fmc_url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
  api_key = ENV['FIREBASE_FCM_API_KEY']
  notification_key = [push_key]
  options = {priority: "normal", content_available: true, notification:   {title: "teste", body: "teste213123" } }
  headers = {
      'Authorization' => "key=#{api_key}",
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
   } 

  body = { to: notification_key }.merge(options)
  params = { body: body.to_json }

  response = RestClient.post(fmc_url, params, headers)
  build_response(response)

end
```

Also have others services as create user, which working fine.. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gehlen what is `push_key`? Is the firebase token for the device?

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano its the firebase key..

Comment: but then the variable `api_key` is equal to `push_key`? If this is true, there is the problem

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano my mistake, is the device key.. On real, I've solved this: the problem was with network.. I gonna release that question. Thank you!

Comment: ahh okok, good to hear that.